# Restore old GRUB to EFI GRUB upgrade to Win 10

Tags: grub2, uefi, restore

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot mode on my computer.

I since upgraded Win 7 to Windows 8 and then to Windows 10.

GRUB obviously has disappeared.

I now want GRUB back. But now Windows 10 I guess is EFI mode while the old Linux mint installation used the traditional GRUB in BIOS.

How do I restore GRUB in such a scenario?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, questions about Mint are of topic here, Ubuntu only, please ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry Mint was an earlier install..its with ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That is NOT what your question said, first you must be clear if you are on Mint any solution given here for Ubuntu may cause issues with your OS as Mint is not == Ubuntu, if not then please first try `boot-repair` from a live medium, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair